# How to add orderby using @query in mongodb repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mongo

I want to add orderby to the following repository method in mongodb with spring. I tried in various methods, but didnt work

```
public interface StageRepository extends MongoRepository<Stage, String> {

     @Query("{$and: [ { 'categoryId': { $eq: ?0 } }, { 'isDeleted': { $eq: ?1 } } ]}")
     public List<Stage> findByCategoryIdAndIsNotDeleted(String categoryId, Boolean deleted);

}
```

I want to add orderby 'order' in the query.

Not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like :

```
@Query("{$and: [ { 'categoryId': { $eq: ?0 } }, { 'isDeleted': { $eq: ?1 } } ]}")
public List<Stage> findByCategoryIdAndIsNotDeleted(String categoryId, Boolean deleted,org.springframework.data.domain.Sort sort);
```

And When you call this method ,create Sort object like below:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC/DESC,"order");
```

Comment: how to add limit to this

Comment: for springboot2.2.1+, Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "order");