# How can I perform more more advanced queries on MongoDB in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am switching from Postgres to MongoDB in my Spring Boot application. I enjoyed the   privilege of being able to query my database using native queries via the `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id\n" +
        "FROM ( \n" +
        "SELECT DISTINCT CASE sender WHEN 1 THEN recipient ELSE sender END AS friend_id \n" +
        "FROM friendrequest WHERE 1 IN (recipient, sender) \n" +
"AND friendrequeststatus = 'ACCEPTED' \n" +
        ") f \n" +
        "LEFT JOIN users u\n" +
        "ON f.friend_id = u.id\n" +
        "ORDER BY friend_id \n-- #pageable\n"
        ,nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> getFriends(Pageable pageable);
```

Presently I am switching to MongoDB, and Inam using the same models. Is it possible to write advanced native queries using the `@Query` method, or am I constrained to using the `Query` object:

```
    user = mongoTemplate.findOne(
  Query.query(Criteria.where("name").is("Jack")), User.class);
```

I asked this question because I haven't seen any articles on building complex queries with MongoDB and Spring Boot.

Comment: You can't do it in SQL, obviously, but you can certainly write a BSON query string in `@Query`; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33017559/3001761. *"I haven't seen any articles"* - how about https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

First You need to understand the difference between RDBMS and NoSQl. You can refer [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-are-the-differences-between-nosql-and-a-traditional-rdbms).

There is a considerable difference between SQL and NoSQL, when querying. As an example MySQl has `select` query keyword and MongoDb has `find({})` function to do get the same output.

Though earlier versions of MongoDb cant perform aggregations, equivalent to SQL join queries, latest versions(>=3.2) allow this from `$lookup`. See the [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Also MongoDb aggregations will help for the code given in the question.

With the understand of NoSql and MongoDb, you can use [Spring MongoDB](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) with complex queries. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53828097/7764309) as a brief workout with Spring and MongoDb.